# I am trying to run a while loop in python and I want to name my dataframes dynamically based on the integration number

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run a while loop in python and I want to name my dataframes dynamically based on the integration number. Below is the code I have -

```
while i < count_keys
key_curr = keys[%i]
temp_%i=mod.copy()
temp_%i.groupby([key_curr]).agg({'iclic_id':"count"})
temp_%i.rename(columns={'count':'CT_'key_curr})
```

I want to know if this way of referencing "%i" is the correct way or is there any other way to reference "i". Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suggest you store the dataframes in a dictionary.  The key would be the dynamically generated name (as a string) and the value would be the dataframe.  Trying to create dynamic variable names is rarely worth the effort.

Comment: Check the indent of your code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i got what you want but my guess is you want to dynamically create variables:

```
while i < count_keys:
    key_curr = keys[i]
    globals()['temp_%i' % i] = mod.copy()
    globals()['temp_%i' % i].groupby([key_curr]).agg({'iclic_id':"count"})
    globals()['temp_%i' % i].rename(columns={'count':'CT_%i' % key_curr})
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this create a dataframe with the name 'temp_1' and so on or a new column?

Comment: New dataframe named `temp_1`

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

dynamic variable names are not recommended. instead, use dictionary to store your data.

for example:

```
my_data = {}
for i, key_curr in enumerate(keys):
    my_data['temp_%d' % i] = mod.copy().groupby([key_curr]).agg({'iclic_id':"count"}).rename(columns={'iclic_id':'CT_' + key_curr})
print my_data.values()
```